# Convolution, indicator function

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

I need to calculate $(f*f)(x)$ of $f(x) = 1_{[0,1]}(x)$, which is the indicator function defined with

[image: The definition of the indicator function]

Calculating the integral $(f*f)(x) = \int_{0,}^{x}1_{[0,1]}(t) \cdot1_{[0,1]}(x-t) dt$ gives $(f*f)(x) = \begin{Bmatrix}
x & \mathbb{for }\space x\in[0,1] \\ 
0 & \mathbb{otherwise}
\end{Bmatrix}$

but the Laplace transformation of $f(x)$ gives the convolution as $(f*f)(x) = x - 2 (x-1)\theta(x-1) + (x-2)\theta(x-2)$, where $\theta(x)$ is the Heavyside theta function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are basically trying to compute the pdf of $\mathcal{U}\ast\mathcal{U}$, where $\mathcal{U}$ is the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$; i.e., the distribution of $Y=X_1+X_2$ where $X_1,X_2$ are independent uniform r.v.s on $[0,1]$. This is known to be the [triangular distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) on $[0,2]$, hinting that your first computation is wrong (also, as a sanity check clearly there should be some probability in the interval $[1,2]$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking carefully at the definition of the integrand (for $x\in\mathbb{R}$), you can see that $f\ast f$ is $0$ for $x\notin[0,2]$, and that for $x\in[0,2]$
$$
f\ast f(x) = \int_{\max(0,x-1)}^{\min(1,x)} dt = \begin{cases} \int_{0}^{x} dt = x & x\leq 1 \\
\int_{x-1}^{1} dt = 2-x & x\geq 1
 \end{cases}
$$
As mentioned in a comment above, you can alternatively get this by seeing that you are computing the probability density function of $D=\mathcal{U}_{[0,1]}\ast\mathcal{U}_{[0,1]}$, where $\mathcal{U}_{[0,1]}$ is the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. This is the distribution of a random variable $Y=X_1+X_2$, where the $X_i$'s are independent uniform r.v.s on $[0,1]$: in particular, $Y$ take values in $[0,2]$, and it is "easy" to see that its density is symmetric around $1$ and that the probability to be around $1/2$ is bigger than the probability to be around $0$ or $1$. (on a side note, $Y$ follows a triangular distribution on $[0,2]$ with mode $1$).

Comment: Additionally, you can prove the result by using the characteristic function (or the Laplace one), if you know the characteristic function of a r.v. distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$: for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\mathbb{E} e^{itY} = \mathbb{E} e^{itX_1+itX_2} = \mathbb{E} e^{itX_1}\cdot\mathbb{E} e^{itX_2} = \left(\mathbb{E} e^{itX_1}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{e^{it}-1}{it}\right)^2 = -\frac{e^{2it-2e^{it}+1}}{t^2}
$$
(where we used independence of the $X_i$'s) and "now it suffices" to notice this is the characteristic function of a $\operatorname{Triang}(0,2,1)$ r.v.

Comment: Dear Clement, maybe you could help me out with this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509418/convolution-of-indicator-functions?noredirect=1#comment3074379_1509418 thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score -1):

The support of the convolution of a function with support $[0,1]$ with itself should have support $[0+0,1+1] = [0,2]$. The convolution integral is non-zero for $x$ in $[1,2]$. If you